# Pre-built class variables in Enum subclass

Tags: python, enums

I'm making a set of Enum classes, and I'd like to build a few iterables over the Enum members up front. Ideally these iterables would be accessible in O(1) time (after the initial build) via a class variable or class method. This should improve speed over my previous version, when I was using class methods that built the iterables on each call in Ω(n) time.

I tried using the `_ignore_` keyword to exclude the iterable class variables from the list of enum members.

```
class Epoch(Enum):
    def id(self) -> int:
        return self.value[0]

    def dt(self) -> datetime:
        return self.value[1]

    @classmethod
    def sortByDate(cls) -> list:
        if len(cls._sortedByDate) == 0:
            cls._sortedByDate = sorted(cls._member_map_.values(), key=lambda x: x.dt())
        return cls._sortedByDate

    @classmethod
    def IDmap(cls) -> dict:
        if len(cls._IDmap) == 0:
            cls._IDmap = {a.id(): a for a in cls}
        return cls._IDmap

    _ignore_ = ['_sortedByDate', '_IDmap']
    # Iterable class variables
    _sortedByDate = []
    _IDmap = dict()

    # Enum members
    e2017_School =         1, datetime(2017,  9,  6,  0,  0, 0)
    e2017_Winter =         2, datetime(2017, 12, 13,  9, 36, 0)
    e2018_School =         3, datetime(2018,  1, 12, 21, 58, 0)
    e2017_Xmas   =         4, datetime(2017, 12, 25,  0,  0, 0)
    # ...Many more enum members
```

But when I call `Epoch.sortByDate()` it appears that those attributes are not only not Enum members, but are also totally inaccessible by/absent from the class.

```
File "C:\Users\...\TimesheetGlobals.py", line 253, in sortByDate
    if len(cls._sortedByDate) == 0:
  File "C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\Timesheet_Data_Analysis\envs\Timesheet_C\lib\enum.py", line 384, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: _sortedByDate
```

Is this not an intended use case for `_ignore_`, or am I just implementing it wrong?
One workaround is to bring the iterable variables (`_sortedByDate`, `_IDmap`) outside the class, but I want to keep them inside; I'd like to put this functionality in an abstract base class and have `Epoch` and several other `Enum` subclasses inherit from it.
If the stdlib `Enum` won't work, then it looks like `aenum`'s `skip` feature might be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is that `_ignore_` also removes the ignored attributes, so the way you are currently trying to use it is not supported.

---

The easiest solution is to check for the attributes' existence instead of their length:

```
if not hasattr(cls._IDmap):
    cls._IDmap = {a.id: a for a in cls}
return cls._IDmap
```

---

You said you were making many such enums?  You could use `__init_subclass__` to create the `_sortedByDate` and `_IDmap` variables after all the members have been created.  This only works in Python 3.11+ or in aenum.

Something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from enum import Enum

class PreIteratedEnum(Enum):

    @property
    def id(self) -> int:
        return self.value[0]

    @property
    def dt(self) -> datetime:
        return self.value[1]

    @classmethod
    def sortByDate(cls) -> list:
        return cls._sortedByDate

    @classmethod
    def IDmap(cls) -> dict:
        return cls._IDmap

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls._sortedByDate = sorted(cls._member_map_.values(), key=lambda x: x.dt)
        cls._IDmap = {a.id: a for a in cls}


class Epoch(PreIteratedEnum):
    # Enum members
    e2017_School =         1, datetime(2017,  9,  6,  0,  0, 0)
    e2017_Winter =         2, datetime(2017, 12, 13,  9, 36, 0)
    e2018_School =         3, datetime(2018,  1, 12, 21, 58, 0)
    e2017_Xmas   =         4, datetime(2017, 12, 25,  0,  0, 0)
```

Note that I also made `id` and `dt` properties.